# Apply Same Transformation to Multiple Returned Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to simplify a query that has much duplication and is doing the same operations to multiple returned values. How can I apply the same `d * 10000` operation to `e`, `g`, `i` to simplify this query?

```
select a, b, c, a + b + c as d,
(a + b + c) * 10000 * e as f,
(a + b + c) * 10000 * g as h,
(a + b + c) * 10000 * i as j
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify with a `lateral join` and `values`, such as

```
select a, b, c, a + b + c as d,
  v * e as f,
  v * g as h,
  v * i as j
from mytable t,
lateral (values((a + b + c) * 10000))x(v);
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=14de25d3adcf056e834ee25e562bf648)

Comment: How would you get this to work if you had `(t.a + t.b + t.c)` and there were other `join`s after `from mytable t`?

Comment: Just join your other table(s), add the lateral join after any joins that you need to reference.

Comment: Do you see a degradation in performance at all from this adjustment?